# Reliable method of cleaning up an external resource associated with an Object

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Concrete use case: There is an abstraction for binary data, which is widely used to handle binary blobs of arbitrary size. Since the abstraction was created without though about things *outside* the VM, existing implementations rely on the garbage collector for their life cycle.

Now I want to add a new implementation that uses off-heap storage (e.g. in a temporary file). Since there is a lot of existing code that uses the abstraction, introducing additional methods for explicit life cycle management is impractical, I can't rewrite every client use case using to ensure they manage the new life cycle requirements.

I can think of two solution approaches, but cant decide which one is better:

a.) Use of finalize() to manage the associated resource's life cycle (e.g. temporary file is deleted in finalize. This *seems* very simple to implement.

b.) Use of a reference queue and java.lang.Reference (but which one, weak or phantom?) with some extra object that deletes the file when the reference is enqueued. This seems to be a bit more work to implement, I would need to create not only the new implementation, but separate out its cleanup data *and* ensure the cleanup object can't be GC'd before the object that has been exposed to the user.

c.) Some other method I haven't though of?

Which approach should I take (and why should I prefer it)? Implementation hints are also welcome.

---

Edit: Degree of reliaility required - for my purpose its perfectly fine if a temporary file is *not* cleaned up in case the VM terminated abruptly. The main concern is that while the VM runs, it could very well fill up the local disk (over the course of a few days) with temporary files (this has happened to me for real with apache TIKA, which created temporary files when extracting text from certain document types, zip files were the culprit I believe). I have a periodic cleanup scheduled on the machine, so if a file drops by cleanup it doesn't mean the end of the world - as long as it doesn't happen regularly in a short interval.

As far as I could determine finalize() works with the Oracale JRE. And if I interpret the javadocs correctly, References *must* work as documented (there is no way a only softly/weakly reachable reference object is not cleared before OutOfMemoryError is thrown). This would mean while the VM may decide not to reclaim a particular object for a long time, it has to do so latest when the heap gets full. In turn this means there can exist only a limited number of my file based blobs on the heap. The VM has to clean them up at some point, or it would definetly run out of memory. Or is there any loophole that allows the VM to run OOM without clearing references (assuming they aren't stronly refered anymore)?

---

Edit2: As far as I see it at this point both finalize() and Reference should be reliable enough for my purposes, but I gather Reference may be the better solution since its interaction with the GC can't revive dead objects and thus its performance impact should be less?

---

Edit3: Solution approaches which rely on VM termination or startup (shutdown hook or similar) are not of use to me, since typically the VM runs for extended periods of time (server environment).

Comment: How "reliable"?  That's the issue.  There are ways, but all have reliability issues.

Comment: The problem with finalizers is that you don't know when (or if) they will run. From Effective Java: *"It is a grave error to depend on a finalizer to close files"*.

Comment: One of java's built in Reference classes IIRC could be used to run some method when the reference expires perhaps

Comment: This doesn't help you now, but I gotta rant. The error is not including methods for explicit deterministic cleanup (and making client code use them) in the first place.

Comment: The problem with approach B is the same as the problem with approach A: the JVM believes that the purpose of garbage collection is to clean up memory, so if it decides that a given bit of memory doesn't need to be cleaned up, then it won't run the corresponding bit of garbage collection.

Comment: @delnan I find the rant a little ... odd. Isn't one of the core goals of managed languages to generally *free* the programmer from explicitly managing life cycles?

Comment: @hotlicks I added some corner points about reliability. I can live with thing not getting cleaned when the VM terminates. I just need to be sure that the number of objects that escape cleanup does not fill the entire local disk.

Comment: @Durandal Regular memory management is indeed automated by garbage collection, and programmers almost never have to care about it. But for many other resources, like connections, files, streams, memory allocated from other devices like GPUs, and even sufficiently large on-heap blobs (such as large bitmaps), deterministic cleanup is extremely useful. These resources have in common that they are very limited (thus freeing them as early as possible is useful and sometimes mandatory), are relatively rare (thus the lifetime worries are manageable) and generally have simple life cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a relevant item from *Effective Java*: [Avoid finalizers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7)

Contained within that item is a recommendation to do just what @delnan suggests in a comment: *provide an explicit termination method*. Plenty of examples provided as well: `InputStream.close()`, `Graphics.dispose()`, etc. Understand that the cows may have already left the barn on that one...

At any rate, here's a sketch of how this might be accomplished with reference objects. First, an interface for binary data:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public interface Blob {
    public byte[] read() throws IOException;
    public void update(byte[] data) throws IOException;
}
```

Next, a file-based implementation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileBlob implements Blob {

    private final File file;

    public FileBlob(File file) {
        super();
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] read() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then, a factory to create and track the file-based blobs:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

public class FileBlobFactory {

    private static final long TIMER_PERIOD_MS = 10000;

    private final ReferenceQueue<File> queue;
    private final ConcurrentMap<PhantomReference<File>, String> refs;
    private final Timer reaperTimer;

    public FileBlobFactory() {
        super();
        this.queue = new ReferenceQueue<File>();
        this.refs = new ConcurrentHashMap<PhantomReference<File>, String>();
        this.reaperTimer = new Timer("FileBlob reaper timer", true);
        this.reaperTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FileBlobReaper(), TIMER_PERIOD_MS, TIMER_PERIOD_MS);
    }

    public Blob create() throws IOException {
        File blobFile = File.createTempFile("blob", null);
        //blobFile.deleteOnExit();
        String blobFilePath = blobFile.getCanonicalPath();
        FileBlob blob = new FileBlob(blobFile);
        this.refs.put(new PhantomReference<File>(blobFile, this.queue), blobFilePath);
        return blob;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        this.reaperTimer.cancel();
    }

    private class FileBlobReaper extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("FileBlob reaper task begin");
            Reference<? extends File> ref = FileBlobFactory.this.queue.poll();
            while (ref != null) {
                String blobFilePath = FileBlobFactory.this.refs.remove(ref);
                File blobFile = new File(blobFilePath);
                boolean isDeleted = blobFile.delete();
                System.out.println("FileBlob reaper deleted " + blobFile + ": " + isDeleted);
                ref = FileBlobFactory.this.queue.poll();
            }
            System.out.println("FileBlob reaper task end");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a test that includes some artificial GC "pressure" to get things going:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileBlobTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileBlobFactory factory = new FileBlobFactory();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                factory.create();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.gc(); System.gc(); System.gc();
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which should produce some output like:

```
FileBlob reaper task begin
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob1055430495823649476.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob873625122345395275.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob4123088770942737465.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob1631534546278785404.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob6150533076250997032.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob7075872276085608840.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob5998579368597938203.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob3779536278201681316.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob8720399798060613253.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper deleted C:\WINDOWS\Temp\blob3046359448721598425.tmp: true
FileBlob reaper task end
```

Comment: I have experimented with a reference based scheme, too. I went a little different route (with one daemon thread for *all* possible implementations), but other than that we seem to have made very similar choices in the general implementation. I think I'll try this and see how well it works out.

Comment: Another approach to keep in mind is to hook the queue processing into a commonly called method (or even multiple methods) and do away with the thread(s). See `WeakHashMap` for an example...

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I cooked up after kschneids reference based example (just in case someone needs a generically usable implementation). Its documented and should be easy to understand/adapt:

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Helper class for cleaning up resources when an object is
 * garbage collected. Use as follows (both anonymous subclass or
 * public subclass are fine. Be extra careful to not retain
 * a reference to the trigger!):
 * 
 * new ResourceFinalizer(trigger) {
 * 
 *     // put user defined state relevant for cleanup here
 *     
 *     protected void cleanup() {
 *         // implement cleanup procedure.
 *     }
 * }
 *
 * Typical application is closing of native resources when an object
 * is garbage collected (e.g. VM external resources).
 * 
 * You must not retain any references from the ResourceFinalizer to the
 * trigger (otherwise the trigger can never become eligible for GC).
 * You can however retain references to the ResourceFinalizer from the
 * trigger, so you can access the data relevant for the finalizer
 * from the trigger (no need to duplicate the data).
 * There is no need to explicitly reference the finalizer after it has
 * been created, the finalizer base class will ensure the finalizer
 * itself is not eligible for GC until it has been run.
 * 
 * When the VM terminates, ResourceFinalizer that haven't been
 * triggered will run, regardless of the state of their triggers
 * (that is even if the triggers are still reachable, the finalizer
 * will be called). There are no guarantees on this, if the VM
 * is terminated abruptly this step may not take place.
 */
public abstract class ResourceFinalizer {

    /**
     * Constructs a ResourceFinalizer that is triggered when the
     * object referenced by finalizationTrigger is garbage collected.
     * 
     * To make this work, you must ensure there are no references to
     * the finalizationTrigger object from the ResourceFinalizer.
     */
    protected ResourceFinalizer(final Object trigger) {
        // create reference to trigger and register this finalizer
        final Reference<Object> reference = new PhantomReference<Object>(trigger, referenceQueue);
        synchronized (finalizerMap) {
            finalizerMap.put(reference, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The cleanup() method is called when the finalizationTrigger
     * has been garbage collected.
     */
    protected abstract void cleanup();

    // --------------------------------------------------------------
    // ---
    // --- Background finalization management
    // ---
    // --------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * The reference queue used to interact with the garbage collector.
     */
    private final static ReferenceQueue<Object> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<Object>();

    /**
     * Global static map of finalizers. Enqueued references are used as key
     * to find the finalizer for the referent.
     */
    private final static HashMap<Reference<?>, ResourceFinalizer> finalizerMap =
            new HashMap<Reference<?>, ResourceFinalizer>(16, 2F);

    static {
        // create and start finalizer thread
        final Thread mainLoop = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finalizerMainLoop();
            }
        }, "ResourceFinalizer");
        mainLoop.setDaemon(true);
        mainLoop.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 1);
        mainLoop.start();

        // add a shutdown hook to take care of resources when the VM terminates
        final Thread shutdownHook = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                shutdownHook();
            }
        });
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
    }

    /**
     * Main loop that runs permanently and executes the finalizers for
     * each object that has been garbage collected. 
     */
    private static void finalizerMainLoop() {
        while (true) {
            final Reference<?> reference;
            try {
                reference = referenceQueue.remove();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                // this will terminate the thread, should never happen
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            final ResourceFinalizer finalizer;
            // find the finalizer for the reference
            synchronized (finalizerMap) {
                finalizer = finalizerMap.remove(reference);
            }
            // run the finalizer
            callFinalizer(finalizer);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the VM shuts down normally. Takes care of calling
     * all finalizers that haven't been triggered yet.
     */
    private static void shutdownHook() {
        // get all remaining resource finalizers
        final List<ResourceFinalizer> remaining;
        synchronized (finalizerMap) {
            remaining = new ArrayList<ResourceFinalizer>(finalizerMap.values());
            finalizerMap.clear();
        }
        // call all remaining finalizers
        for (final ResourceFinalizer finalizer : remaining) {
            callFinalizer(finalizer);
        }
    }

    private static void callFinalizer(final ResourceFinalizer finalizer) {
        try {
            finalizer.cleanup();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // don't care if a finalizer throws
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not particularly worried about cleaning up the files quickly, then `finalize` is the way to go.  There is no guarantee that any particular object is ever GC'd, even if you run out of memory (the VM could in theory only collect part of the heap).  But if an object is GC'd it will be finalized, so you know that you will have at most sizeof(heap) / sizeof(in-memory handle) unfinalized blobs, which puts some bound on your disk usage.  It's a pretty weak bound, but it sounds like it might be good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, just doing it in your finalizers is not a bad solution that will at least close a good proportion of your files, probably. If that's good enough, I'd go down that route, because it'll be far easier.

On the other hand, if you're looking for any certainty then using finalizers is very bad; you can't depend on them being run ever, let alone in a timely manner, and this same argument applies more loosely for clean-up of the various special types of reference too. It rather depends on the details of your application, and your hardware, but in general you have no guarantee that the references will be cleaned before your disk fills up.

This is more likely to happen if the data you're holding in memory (which is taking most of the space) is substantial but very short-lived, while the file references last much longer. This results in lots of minor garbage collections, which will clean the young generation space, delete the dead data and eventually promote many of the file references, but results in no major garbage collections, which would clear older tenured objects such as your file references, so those are then kept alive indefinitely. Check out [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) for more GC background. You might be able to improve how many of your finalizers actually get hit by increasing the young generation size, in exchange for slightly slower GCs.

If you do want more certainty, I'd solve the problem slightly differently. First, implement clean-up in finalizers as a quick simple-case solution. Then build a fallback too; decide on a maximum amount of space that you're prepared to have your files take, preferably substantially more than you expect to actually be using, monitor the total space you're using every X minutes, and if it cross this bound then delete a selection of the oldest (by last write time) files, e.g. the oldest 10%. This gives you a fairly hard upper bound, and you can probably keep the check frequency very low here, since the finalizers should hopefully catch most issues.

One other note that I think might be semi-relevant is [deleteOnExit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29). Calling this on your temporary files when they are created will guarantee they are automatically deleted when the JVM exits successfully. This does have [downsides](http://puneeth.wordpress.com/2006/01/23/filedeleteonexit-is-evil/) though: the JVM must hold a reference to this file until it closes, which leaves you with a small memory leak (1K per file, I believe). Not sure whether that makes it worthwhile to you, but might help!

Comment: deleteOnExit doesn't help me - the same code is used in client and server. The server is typically restarted only once every few *weeks* to install updates. So assume the VM never exits. Sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: Fair enough, scrap that bit. Nonetheless, a background cleanup thread gives you what you need if you do want guarantees, which you probably do by the sound of it. You can actually improve it further if you have an upper bound on how often files get written to, since you can just delete everything that hasn't been written to within that time whenever you check.